# Windows 2012 Server Hyper-V: Cannot see LAN

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have one NIC on the machine loaded XP on the Hyper-V and had chosen the network as virtual switch. No LAN and no internet shows up on the client. Am I missing something? it used to work in 2008-R2.

Details:

- One network card on machine (Qualcomm Atheros AR8131 PIC-E Gigabit Ethernet controller)
- The virtual machine hard disk is pointing to and existing XP-SP2 hard disk created using VPC 2007
- The Virtual machine Network Adapter is setup as Virtual Switch to the real ethernet controller with Enable virtual LAN identification set to 2 (no other virtual machine is created in the system)

After the virtual machine boots LAN shows empty in Control Panel > Network Connections (this is XP client) and I also cannot access the internet. XP is showing activation prompt but as far as I know it should not disable the network!

Virtual network switch is set to External

Comment: `Am I missing something?`  Yes.  For starters, enough details or information to make this answerable.

Comment: sorry, thought I was missing something obvious... now added some more details

Comment: why did you enable vlan id, don't unless you use vlans.

Comment: Thanks, just tried to experiment with it when it was not working otherwise...

Comment: is there only one nic on this server, also did you check share this network with management?

Comment: Yes there is only one nic on the server and the box "Allow management operating system to share this network" is checked

Comment: so do you know if you have vlans trunked on this particular nic?

Comment: I am not sure what the vlan trunking means, need to look it up :), I just installed the 2012 server on this machine and created a new VM using a previous disk. Did not do any other setting changes...

Comment: have not even bothered to look but is xp a supported guest?

Comment: This may be the problem... did not ever assume that only XP-SP3 is the supported guest. Have a bunch of VM disk with SP2 as some of our customers did not bother to upgrade! Probably need to go back to 2008-R2 again! However, I will test with SP3 and update here.

Comment: see if you can install the integration components, officially xp including sp3 is not supported on windows 2012 but it may still work fine after installing the components.

Comment: I did install the components but that does not bring up the LAN

Comment: looks like sp3 is the supported guest (http://blogs.virtualizationadmin.com/lowe/2012/08/19/supported-guest-operating-systems-in-hyper-v-2012/)

Comment: there is a lot of confusing surrounding xp and the newest hyper-v. xp I think is only supported on the the desktop version of hyper-v not the server version.  But I don't think thats your problem in this case.

Comment: get anywhere on this?

Comment: Just tried today by upgrading my virtual machine from SP2 to SP3 and rebooted the machine. The network is still not showing up. So either the server Hyper-V does not support XP-SP3 (which is what you said) or maybe there is something I am not setting correctly.

Comment: can you boot up a windows 7 guest?

Comment: Tried to add my Windows 2008 VM and that is also not working. The Network Adapter is not showing up in the device manager. Also under the System devices it says "Microsoft Hyper-V Virtual machine Bus could not be started because there is not much free resources (I have 500mb of free memory left).

Comment: so hame much ram are you assigning to these vm's?

Comment: 2Gb for windows 2008 and 512 MB for XP. Could this be a problem... not likely!

Comment: I can try with windows 7 but I need to do the full installation. Somehow I feel that the problem is somewhere else!

Comment: Hi Tony, got it fixed, it was very simple to do but hard to figure out. See my reply below.

Answer (score 2):

> •The Virtual machine Network Adapter is setup as Virtual Switch to the real ethernet controller 
>   with Enable virtual LAN identification set to 2 (no other virtual machine is created in the system)

Ok, so do you expect the traffic to be tagged with VLAN ID 2? If not, why do you consider it necessary to set a VLAN id? Did you make sure the Ethernet Card is handling and Pasing through tagged traffic? Some do not without reconfiguring.

Comment: Just was testing various things (trial and error in the dark) to see if I can make it to work. Most of the time this strategy works for me :). I just checked that only XP-SP3 is the supported guest so this could be  the issue because my current VM is XP-SP2

Comment: Ok, so you dont know what you do - start by reading the documentation or hire an admin ;)

Comment: I am going to read all that but first I need to play with it little bit to bring something up. This works just fine on 2008-R2!

Answer (score 0):

I tried hundred things to get this fixed but nothing worked.

Then I posted to the ms forum and got a reply that I should uninstall the integration services and then reboot and reinstall it. Just did the same thing and the network came back!